# How to install gromacs 4.5.5 and upgrade to gromacs 4.6.3?

Tags: software-installation

So, I tried to install gromacs 4.6.3 and 4.6.5.

but when I tried it says gromacs not found.

and "The program "genbox" is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install gromacs"

so I did that. what I have now is gromacs 4.5.5.

I want 4.6.3 or 4.6.5

How can I delete the 4.5.5 and have the 4.6.3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Remov gromacs 4.5.5 by running the below command,

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge gromacs
  ```
- Then download latest gromacs version from [here](http://www.gromacs.org/Downloads).
- Follow [this](http://www.gromacs.org/Documentation/Installation_Instructions#GROMACS_installation_guide) installation guide to install the latest version.

Comment: yes, I already downloaded that gromacs 4.6.5. I already have it on the downloads folder. I tried to follow the commands on the installation guide but it says that gromacs is not installed. :(

Comment: plz post the command did you followed and it's output.